# Need some knowledge on Struct and specially property wrapper

Tags: swift, properties, didset

```
struct XA {

static var xa = "Advanced"

var xb: String {
    didSet {
        XA.xa = oldValue
    }
}}

var objXA = XA(xb: "Turing")
print(XA.xa) // Advanced
objXA.xb = "Swift"
print(XA.xa) // Turing

let objXB = XA(xb: "Quiz")
print(XA.xa) // Turing
```

> i need to understand how these output coming in little bit depth. On the last line why its printing Turing not Swift.

Comment: Same reason it's printing "Advanced" after `objXA` was created, `didSet` is never called for a property when it is set in an `init` method.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson objXA.xb = "Swift" After this line still did set not called?.

Comment: It is called after `objXA.xb = "Swift"`, but it is not called when you do `XA(xb: "Quiz")` or `XA(xb: "Turing")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason, as Joakim says in their comment, is that initializers do not invoke didSet/willSet. That's by design.

To Quote the Apple Swift eBook (emphasis added by me)

> The willSet and didSet observers of superclass properties are called
> when a property is set in a subclass initializer, after the superclass
> initializer has been called. **They aren’t called while a class is
> setting its own properties, before the superclass initializer has been
> called.** For more information about initializer delegation, see
> Initializer Delegation for Value Types and Initializer Delegation for
> Class Types.

Excerpt From
The Swift Programming Language (Swift 5.7)
Apple Inc.
https://books.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-5-7/id881256329
This material may be protected by copyright.